# How to apply permissions with Facebook4j?

Tags: java, facebook4j

I downloaded the latest jar file from: http://facebook4j.github.io/en/index.html

This is my code:

```
Facebook fb = new FacebookFactory().getInstance();
fb.setOAuthAppId("ID", "Pass");
fb.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(accesstoken)); // I get from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
fb.postStatusMessage("tester post");
```

I got an exception when I tried to post status:

```
SEVERE: null
message - (#200) Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission
code - 200
Relevant information for error recovery can be found on the Facebook Developers Document:
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved that.
Because I got accessToken API Graph v3.0, it don't have publish_actions permission, so I got Exception.

I get v2.12, It's ok